# linq to entities contains does not work

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am new to linq to entities and I have a problems in using the contain method.
Here is the sample table in my DB.

```
DataTable UserTable = new DataTable();
UserTable .Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
UserTable .Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

UserTable .Rows.Add(1,"Tom");
UserTable .Rows.Add(2,"Tom_dad");
UserTable .Rows.Add(3,"Tom_mom");
UserTable .Rows.Add(4,"Tom_sister");
```

In Linq to entities I wrote the statement

```
entities edm = new entities();
var query= from a in edm .UserTable 
           where a.Name.Contains("Tom")
           select a;
```

The result is only first row where the name is exactly Tom.

How can I get results that included 4 rows? Such as SQL LIKE method %Tom%.

Thanks for your help and kindness.

Environments : VS2010 / .Net FrameWork4

//Update//

Thanks a lot to Ben Millane.
It works after I add the ToList() behind the statement.

```
var query= (from a in edm .UserTable 
               where a.Name.Contains("Tom")
               select a).ToList();
```

What is the difference between the two statements? I wander why this improvement can work.

Comment: If UserTable has a Row called "Name" and contains 4 records with Tom in it--your query should work.

Comment: That is how you do it. I think you are missing something elsewhere.

Comment: Don't you do a `FirstOrDefault()` or  `First()` somewhere on your `query` object ? Cause this should be perfectly correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
entities edm = new entities();
var query= (from a in edm .UserTable 
       where a.Name.Contains("Tom")
       select a).ToList();
```

Does that work?

Comment: Clarification: by wrapping your query in a `ToList()` you force the query to run immediately. If this fixes your problem it is because you are making the query, changing the data, then actually running it.